# A "Nice" way to get substring between an opening and a matching closing tag (parantheses etc.)

Tags: java, string

I quite frequently run into the task of extracting a substring from a string which is located between an opening tag (such as "(") and a closing tag (for example ")"), **such that the "level" of the opening tag matches the "level" of the closing tag**.

For example, in the following string,

```
((a + (b * c) + d) + e)
```

when given the index 1 (pointing to the second opening tag "(" in the string), I would be interested in the substring

```
(a + (b * c) + d)
```

I'm NOT interested in the part until the first closing tag:

```
(a + (b * c)
```

In addition to one-character tags, longer strings (e.g., "begin", "end") should work, too. It is not hard to solve this, but I always find my running through the string in a loop quite ugly, possibly inefficient and error-prone.

**Is there a nice way to do this?**

(Maybe there is some regex hack? But they won't work directly due to the need of counting.)

Comment: Loop seems to be fine solution. You need to simply count `(` and `)` and stop when number of `)` will be greater than `(` and remember how many characters you iterated. I doubt that you will be able to do it faster. If you need to repeat this task few times only thing you can do to improve your performance is to store results in some structure (like tree or maybe map).

Comment: Found [this one](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/) using Google search.

Comment: To further elaborate on @Pshemo 's advice on using a structure: You could fill a *Tree* (since mathematical operations are indeed trees (left, operand, right) when parsing the parenthesizes.

Comment: One thing which makes it still more difficult (a little) is that often the opening and closing tags have more than one character. It's just a somewhat messy task overall - even when doing it recursively... Using a more elaborate structure is surely a good idea, but it does not improve the part of parsing the string

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do something similar to this, but using `<` and `>` instead.

The best way in my opinion is to just iterate the string, and keep a stack of 'open' and 'close' tags as you go along. When you hit a point where the number of open and close tags are the same, you know you've found a substring. This method would require recursion/loops as once you parsed the outermost case you still have inner cases.

Alternatively, you could do the same, but as soon as you hit a close tag, parse the substring of the last open tag and the close tag. This method would be harder to keep track of as Strings are immutable.

If you want any code examples I can provide them, but string parsing is pretty fun to learn

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex to match inner parenthesis: `([^()]*)`

It matches all inner parenthesis, and you can substitute them by some expression until you get the substring you desire (in your case, the substring starting at index 1). Then you replace the expressions back.

I used this to solve math equations and recursively solve parenthesis.

Comment: I like this idea! Will certainly try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through characters increasing opened parantheses count every time character is equal to '(' and decreasing when character is equal to ')'. You will have your substring end index when your count is equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to do that recursively by the opening and closing tags. 
Like this:

- remove open tag and close tag at the left and the right
- remove left until opening tag
- remove rigth until closing tag
- aso

On this way you only should define the depth of the recursion for the `subString`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is my own "ugly" solution to the question by simply iterating through the string (it doesn't catch any exceptions in case a tag is missing or something else goes wrong; it should be correct in case the string is well-formed as it has been tested extensively in the meantime):

```
public static String extractSubstringLevelwise(
        String string, 
        String beginTag, 
        String endTag, 
        int beginTagPos) {
    int curPos = beginTagPos;
    int count = 1;

    while (count != 0) {
        int curBegin = string.indexOf(beginTag, curPos + 1);
        int curEnd = string.indexOf(endTag, curPos + 1);

        if (curBegin < 0) {
            curBegin = curEnd;
        }

        if (curEnd < 0) {
            curEnd = curBegin;
        }

        if (curEnd > curBegin) {
            count++;
            curPos = curBegin;
        } else {
            count--;
            curPos = curEnd;
        }
    }

    return string.substring(beginTagPos + beginTag.length(), curPos);
}
```

**I'm still looking for a "nicer" solution :-)**